# playing track in random order java

Tags: java, random, arraylist, shuffle

do I on the right track? this must play every track in arraylist once in random order.

```
public void randomAllTrack() { 

    int shuffle = getNumberOfTracks();
    int shuffleplay = randomTrack.nextInt(shuffle);
    Track track = tracks.get(shuffleplay);
    int i=0;

    while(i < getNumberOfTracks())
    {player.startPlaying(track.getFilename());
        System.out.println("Now playing: " + track.getArtist() + " - "
        + track.getTitle());
        i++;}
}
```

Comment: Almost but you need a way to keep track of which songs you have already heard so unless you remove them from track then you will play the same songs multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `tracks` is a `Collection`, you could use a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) after doing a [`Collections.shuffle(List)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-), and I you could use formatted IO. Something like

```
public void randomAllTrack() {
    List<Track> randomTracks = new ArrayList<>(tracks);
    Collections.shuffle(randomTracks);
    for (Track track : randomTracks) {
        player.startPlaying(track.getFilename());
        System.out.printf("Now playing: %s - %s%n", track.getArtist(),
                track.getTitle());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it plays all the tracks at the same time. how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `List` and use `Collection` if you just need an initial shuffle:

    `List<Track> tracks = new ArrayList<>();
    Collections.shuffle(tracks);
    for (Track track :  tracks) {
        System.out.println("Playing track: " track.getFilename());
    }`